# Resolving async value from JS class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, request, vuex

In short: I need to request a token from Auth0 in order to then retrieve user information (all inside a Vue plugin that is called by Vuex).

I currently have two classes - one for dealing with the token and the other for actually retrieving the profile.

```
export class Token {
  constructor () {
    this.options = { method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://.auth0.com/oauth/token',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: '{"client_id":"","client_secret":"","audience":"","grant_type":"client_credentials"}' }
  }

  async getToken () {
     try {
       this.request = request(this.options, function (error, response, body) {
         if (error) {
           console.error(error)
         } else {
           let parsed = JSON.parse(body)
           let token = parsed.access_token
           return token
         }
       })
       let blah = await this.request
       console.log(blah)
     } catch (err) {
       console.error(err)
     }
  }
}

export default class Profile {
  constructor () {
    const token = new Token()
    let result = token.getToken()
    //console.log(result)
    this.auth0Manage = new auth0.Management({
      domain: '.auth0.com',
      token: `${result}`
    })
  }

  getProfile () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let idToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token')
      let decoded = jwt_decode(idToken)
      let userId = decoded.sub
      this.auth0Manage.getUser(userId, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
        resolve(data)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

I am expecting the following flow:

Get token > Get profile. It doesn't have to be in two classes (originally it wasn't but I couldn't instantiate the constructor for Profile without getting the token first, which would have to be its own class (afaik). Thanks!

Comment: Could you please specify the problem you're having? My guess is that result in your Profile constructor isn't resolved when used in Auth0Manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not awaiting your getToken result in the profile constructor. Problem is, constructors are always synchronous. So in order to await the token, you need to do something like make `Profile#auth0manage` an async value and await that. Maybe like:

```
export default class Profile {
  constructor () {
    let token = new Token()
    this.auth0Manage = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      token.getToken().then((result) => {
        return new auth0.Management({
          domain: '.auth0.com',
          token: `${result}`
        })
      }).then(resolve, reject)
    })
  }

  async getProfile () {
    let auth0Manage = await this.auth0Manage
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let idToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token')
      let decoded = jwt_decode(idToken)
      let userId = decoded.sub
      auth0Manage.getUser(userId, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
        resolve(data)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Caveats of this are that if you get an error in `getToken` then every call to `getProfile` will return the same error. So you may want to handle that somehow. Also, you have to remember to await every use of `this.auth0Manage`. Ideally, you could do something like pass in the auth0Manager to the constructor of Profile, so that you won't event try to make a profile until the token has been fetched. Tends to work out better to do things that way.

Comment: Thanks! Modifying `getToken` to `resolve()` instead of `return` did the trick. I now see the token finally being passed into the second class.

Comment: Oh yeah, request does take a callback that you might want to handle with a promise... good catch, I missed that. However, You might want to uses a version of `request` that returns a promise ([docs](https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait)). That will simplify some of the code here, and then you can use return, instead of having to make a promise and resolve.